# Query to get value from two columns

Tags: php, mysql

I need to write a query to retrieve values from two columns using mysql table

My table has the following strucutre

```
| ID | to_user_id | from_user_id | message |        datetime     | 
| 1  |     21     |      07      |   hi    | 2012-05-10 04:13:01 | 
| 2  |     07     |      21      |  hello  | 2012-05-10 04:17:51 |
```

I want to write a query to get both messages user send and get in single query

Comment: `SELECT message FROM yourtable WHERE to_user_id = $id OR from_user_id = $id` ?

Comment: @DamienPirsy:i want get  these users (07,21) messages only query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `to_user_id` = 21 OR `from_user_id` = 21
```

It'll get the rows where user with id 21 is sender and receiver.

Answer (score 2):

Try Simple and execute

```
SELECT `message` FROM `table` WHERE `to_user_id` = 21 OR `from_user_id` = 21
```